# Purging deleted external user from AzureAD / Office 365 fails with UserNotFoundException

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, office365

I am trying to purge a deleted user from Office 365 / AzureAD. The way to do this seems to be [`Remove-MsolUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/remove-msoluser?view=azureadps-1.0) with the `-RemoveFromRecycleBin` flag.

I can retrieve the user with

```
Get-MsolUser -All -ReturnDeletedUsers | ? {$_.userPrincipalName -eq $USERNAME}
```

When I try to remove it with

```
Remove-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $USERNAME -RemoveFromRecycleBin
```

I get

```
Remove-MsolUser : User Not Found in the Microsoft Online directory Deleted Users container.  User:
xxxxxx#EXT#@yyyyyyyyy.
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
+ Remove-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $USERNAME -RemoveFromRecycleBin
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Remove-MsolUser], MicrosoftOnlineException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.UserNotFoundException,Microsoft.Online.Admini
   stration.Automation.RemoveUser
```

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3019157/remove-msoluser-user-not-found-error-when-you-try-to-remove-a-user-fro states

> This problem occurs if the user who is performing the action is not a global admin.

However my using **is** global admin.

Comment: What happens if you directly pipe `Remove-MsolUser` after the `Get-MsolUser` line?

Comment: You may want to try the AzureAD commands instead of the MSOL commands.  See
[Connect to O365 PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/powershell/connect-to-office-365-powershell) and [Remove-AzureADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/remove-azureaduser?view=azureadps-2.0)

Comment: @Theo, I tried your suggestion and it worked. Thanks :) Do you want to add it as an answer, so that I can mark it as accepted?

Comment: I have added my comment as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case it would be better to pipe the output of `Get-MsolUser -All -ReturnDeletedUsers | ? {$_.userPrincipalName -eq $USERNAME}` directly to the `Remove-MsolUser`.
That way, the `ObjectID` property is used instead of the UserPrincipalName which looks to have been changed (`#EXT#`) once added to the Recycle bin.

The `ObjectID` (a guid) however is not changed and uniquely identifies the user object.

Try:

```
Get-MsolUser -All -ReturnDeletedUsers | ? {$_.userPrincipalName -eq $USERNAME} |
Remove-MsolUser -RemoveFromRecycleBin
```

Or:

```
$exUser = Get-MsolUser -All -ReturnDeletedUsers | ? {$_.userPrincipalName -eq $USERNAME}
Remove-MsolUser -ObjectId $exUser.ObjectID -RemoveFromRecycleBin
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use the older MSOnline V1 PowerShell module for Azure Active Directory, you need to delete the guest user from the recycle bin with setting the username as the real email address of the guest user.

For example, if the guest user is aaa@outlook.com. It will be listed as aaa_outlook.com#EXT#@***.onmicrosoft.com with `Get-MsolUser`. But you need set `$USERNAME = "aaa@outlook.com"` instead of `"aaa_outlook.com#EXT#@***.onmicrosoft.com"`.

Then you will be able to delete it from the recycle bin.